# problem fixing : ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Tags: ssh

It worked fine before I installed zsh to decorate my terminal. Actually I am not sure if this caused a problem.

I am getting an error saying : 
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

```
➜ ssh test_ssh
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

➜ ssh -v test_ssh
OpenSSH_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/mike/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/mike/.ssh/config line 34: Applying options for test_ssh
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 52: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 15.164.49.113 port 7779.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mike/.ssh/key/admin.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mike/.ssh/key/admin.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6
debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

Comment: I am having a similar error `ssh cnode0295
ssh: connect to host XXX port 22: Resource temporarily unavailable
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`. I received the error after attempting to run ssh in with gnu parallel.

Comment: have you fixed the problem? I am still struggling...

Comment: The problem has been solved. It turns out there was a firewall problem on the server side.

Comment: So it wasn't a problem with gnu??

Comment: I am wondering if gnu parallel could have induced the problem on the server side as multiple connection attempts may result in inducing security measures on the server side. Now I am simply compressing all the filed before sending them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my own case, I was able to log in from my ssh and got this error when I try to login directly to my VPS from my MacBook terminal

HOW I SOLVE THIS ERROR
**ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by the remote host**

(this always occur when you create a new user on your VPS. you will get this error because you have only ssh configuration for root, not the new user)

**on your mac book terminal**
type
    $  cd ~/.ssh

now
    `~/.ssh create a config file with the following content:` 
    $ nano config

and copy this

```
  Host *
     ForwardAgent no
     ForwardX11 no
     ForwardX11Trusted yes
     User shapeshed
     Port 22
     Protocol 2
```

save and exit

type

```
$ ls
```

result

> authorized_keys   id_rsa      id_rsa1.pub
>   config      id_rsa.pub  known_hosts

`$ cat id_rsa.pub` (to view your public key on macOS terminal )

copy your mac os terminal public key and contr X to exit (if you also use nano text editor)

now on your VPS(remote server)
 make sure you are login as the new user created

user@...... not root

```
 $ cd ~/.ssh
 $ ls
```

note that you have just

> authorized_keys  known_hostsas your result ... no public key for the VPS to recognize signing in from your computer
>     now let's create new id_rsa.pub on our VPS

```
$ nano id_rsa.pub
```

paste your mac os id_rsa.pub you copied save and exit.

type

```
$  ssh -vvv user@**.**.**.**
```

replace  ** with your IP and see your VPS logged in from your terminal without asking for a password.

### bazzlylinksSolution

Answer (score 0):

I just turn off proxy software, such as Shadowsockets. It will be OK. Because I have turned on global mode.